# Selenium Server - Accept only 1 IP

Tags: selenium

I got a Selenium server all set up, and for security reasons, I want to make it accept requests from just a specific IP. Is there a way to configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure a firewall on the machine on which your selenium server is running. The firewall would only accept incoming connections from one specific IP.

Comment: is it possible to make changes to the Selenium jar file so that it accepts a specific IP? It is a Jetty server.

Comment: I haven't checked it but I guess that it is possible. My recommendation is that you don't change the jar file. If you would change the jar file you would have to do it with every update of selenium. Another reason is that I think that it is easier setting up a firewall than changing resp. patching the selenium jar.